# XSLT extension method with variable number of arguments

Tags: extension-methods, xslt, umbraco, xslcompiledtransform

I'm trying to implement an XSLT extension function with variable number of arguments. If I declare the parameter as an array, a params array, a ICollection, etc. I get the following error (where TYPE_NAME is the type used):

System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: Extension function parameters or return values which have Clr type 'TYPE_NAME' are not supported.

But the Umbraco has a built-in function `concat` which functions in this way. I looked in Umbraco's source and it looks like this:

```
public static string concat(XPathNodeIterator nodeset){...}
```

and in XSLT it is called like this:

```
concat('a', 'b', 'c')
```

When I try a similar approach and declare my function as follows:

```
public static string Test(XPathNodeIterator nodeset){...}
```

and call it in XSLT in the same way:

```
Custom:Test('a', 'b', 'c')
```

I get the following error:

> System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: Extension object 'urn:Custom' does not contain a matching 'Test' method that has 3 parameter(s).

I guess the input of concat is somehow transformed in XPathNodeIterator but I am unable to figure how. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are two problems with what you are doing**:

1. Methods with the `params` keyword are not supported as extension functions, as specified in the **[.NET documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject.aspx)**:

> **Remarks**
>
> *The params keyword, which allows an unspecified number of parameters to be passed, is currently not supported. XSLT style sheets that
>   utilize methods defined with the params keyword does not work
>   correctly. For more information, see params (C# Reference).*

.2. Only certain types are allowed as parameters for extension functions. These are defined **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfktf882.aspx)**:

```
W3C type             Equivalent .NET class (type)             XPath or XSLT type

String                     System.String                           XPath

Boolean                    System.Boolean                          XPath

Number                     System.Double                           XPath

Result Tree Fragment       System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator         XSLT

Node*                      System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator         XPath

Node Set                   XPathNodeIterator or XPathNavigator[]   XPath
```

Comment: But the umbraco's concat extension method works somehow. It can be called with an arbitrary number of string arguments. But in the implementation there's only one argument of the XPathNodeIterator type. I suppose it somehow creates an XPathNodeIterator from those strings. I just cannot find out how.

Comment: You seem to be confused. `concat()` is a *standard* XPath function. It is (as exception of the rule) the only function that can have variable number of arguments. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-concat . My guess is that the Umbraco function you cite isn't used as extension function but just internally in Umbraco.

Comment: Aaaaah, now i get it. Now that you mention it, it was a little bit strange that concat was called with no prefix. Thanx